# [Odoo][v13] Search on tree view on from view

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

I wanna add search for tree view which is located on form view in Odoov13.
This tree form is one2many field.

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: The widgets are not made for this requirement, so you IMO have two options: Extending the JavaScript widgets (have fun doing that ;-)) OR using a smartbutton (like "x Deliverys" in sales orders) which opens a real list view with search view. In almost every case i've stumbled over your requirement the second option was enough for the customer.

Comment: And another hint: One2many fields in views with lots of entries tend to reduce load performance. So try to avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: @CZoellner Extending the JavaScript widgets is the last thing that i wanna do :D 
 smartbutton (like "x Deliverys" in sales orders)  --> Can you show me screenshot where it is and how it look? I can't find this.

Comment: try following [link](https://5413528-14-0.runbot45.odoo.com/web#id=48&action=1108&model=sale.order&view_type=form&cids=1&menu_id=789). It doesn't have deliveries but tasks and timesheets instead. Login in Odoo's runbot is admin/admin or demo/demo.